# How to identify 3 layer combinations from different lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, image

I have two different lists (list1 and list2) of image datasets. I want to determine possible three feature combinations considering the integration of both lists, but not individually. list1 is the main dataset and list2 is ancillary data. I am already familiar with `itertools.combinations` but I don't know how to solve the current problem. Can anyone suggest a solution in python?

```
list1= ["a","b","c","d","e"]

list2= ["a1", "a2","a3","a4",
        "a5","a6","a7","a8",
        "a9","a10","a11","a12"]
```

---

example for five possible combinations:

```
combinations=[('a', 'a1', 'a2'), ('a', 'b', 'a2'), ('b', 'a1', 'a2'), ('b', 'c', 'a3'), ('a', 'a2', 'a3')]
```

---

I tested the proposed solution for two small lists and this produce repetition of members in some combinations.

```
list1= ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2= ['a1', 'a2']
```

result:

```
{('d', 'c', 'a2'), ('c', 'a2', 'a1'), ('e', 'b', 'a1'), ('c', 'd', 'a1'), ('e', 'a2', 'a1'), ('a', 'a', 'a2'), ('b', 'a2', 'a1'), ('d', 'd', 'a1'), ('d', 'a', 'a2'), ('a', 'b', 'a2'), ('a', 'e', 'a2'), ('e', 'a1', 'a1'), ('d', 'e', 'a2'), ('c', 'a', 'a2'), ('c', 'c', 'a2'), ('c', 'e', 'a2'), ('b', 'd', 'a1'), ('a', 'c', 'a1'), ('e', 'd', 'a1'), ('d', 'b', 'a2'), ('e', 'c', 'a2'), ('d', 'c', 'a1'), ('b', 'c', 'a2'), ('b', 'e', 'a2'), ('c', 'b', 'a2'), ('a', 'a', 'a1'), ('a', 'a1', 'a2'), ('d', 'a', 'a1'), ('a', 'e', 'a1'), ('a', 'b', 'a1'), ('b', 'a', 'a2'), ('d', 'a1', 'a2'), ('d', 'e', 'a1'), ('e', 'e', 'a2'), ('a', 'a2', 'a2'), ('c', 'a', 'a1'), ('c', 'c', 'a1'), ('a', 'd', 'a2'), ('d', 'a2', 'a2'), ('c', 'a1', 'a2'), ('c', 'e', 'a1'), ('b', 'a1', 'a1'), ('d', 'b', 'a1'), ('e', 'a', 'a2'), ('e', 'c', 'a1'), ('b', 'b', 'a2'), ('b', 'a1', 'a2'), ('b', 'c', 'a1'), ('e', 'b', 'a2'), ('c', 'a2', 'a2'), ('c', 'd', 'a2'), ('b', 'e', 'a1'), ('c', 'b', 'a1'), ('e', 'a2', 'a2'), ('a', 'a1', 'a1'), ('d', 'd', 'a2'), ('b', 'a2', 'a2'), ('b', 'a', 'a1'), ('e', 'a1', 'a2'), ('d', 'a1', 'a1'), ('e', 'e', 'a1'), ('a', 'a2', 'a1'), ('a', 'd', 'a1'), ('e', 'd', 'a2'), ('d', 'a2', 'a1'), ('c', 'a1', 'a1'), ('b', 'd', 'a2'), ('a', 'c', 'a2'), ('e', 'a', 'a1'), ('b', 'b', 'a1')}
```

example of repetition: `('c', 'a1', 'a1')`

Comment: Can you give an example of, say, five elements from this set of combinations you seek?

Comment: @ Captain Trojan, question is updated. They are image datasets and I only want to determine possible 3 layer combinations.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean by "three layer combinations". Try to abstract the redundant information out of the core problem you're trying to solve, and if you can, show us the example expected output with respect to those lists you've given as an example.

Comment: @ Captain Trojan, Please see the question for the example of itertools.combinations

Comment: You still don't understand. I don't need an example of `itertools.combinations`. I need an example of what you, the problem author, expect to see as the output of creation of "3 layer combinations" from `list1` and `list2`.  Can you show us five members of the output?

Comment: @ Captain Trojan, example of five members of the possible output is added to the question. please have a look.

Comment: Hopefully last specifying question (and thank you for providing the example set): Does this mean that each combination member has either a) one member from `list1` and two members from `list2` or b) two members from `list1` and one member from `list2`?

Comment: @ Captain Trojan, Thanks for the reply. That is true. Either a or b. This means the combination of both lists are required in the result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After gathering all the information required, my proposed solution is to use a `product` instead:

```
from itertools import product

def apply_op(list1, list2):
   part_1 = product(list1, list1, list2)
   part_2 = product(list1, list2, list2)
   return set(list(part_1)).union(set(list(part_2)))

print(apply_op(A, B))
```

EDIT: above solution doesn't work, since the result contains duplicate members in tuples.

```
def apply_op(list1, list2):
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list1)):
            for k in range(len(list2)):
                ret.append((list1[i], list1[j], list2[k]))
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            for k in range(j + 1, len(list2)):
                ret.append((list1[i], list2[j], list2[k]))
    return ret

print(apply_op(A, B))
```

Comment: @ Captain Trojan, Thanks for the solution. I run the code but it does not display the output.

Comment: @Sam Okay, now it explicitly prints the solution. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @ Captain Trojan, I printed the result and it returned "name 'result' is not defined". Also, I printed (apply_op(list1, list2)) and this returned None.

Comment: Are you sure you used the code from my answer @Sam ?

Comment: @ Captain Trojan, Please see the question. The solution creates repetition in some combinations.

Comment: @Sam I edited the code. What do you think about this?

Comment: @ Captain Trojan. Thank you. The edited code works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is exactly that you want, but if you want to merge two lists based on inputs in first lists, I suggest you to use dictionary. You can put element in list1 as key and put elements of list2 two in list, a value to that key. you can then use dictionary methods to update those value lists.

Comment: I update the question with link to itertools.combinations for single list. As stated in the question, I have now two different lists and I am not interested with 3 layer combinations from individual lists.